# Jenkins Git Hook script not being ran

Tags: git, batch-file, jenkins, git-svn, githooks

**Disclaimer:**
I am aware there are a million questions and resources about this topic and I have read and tried just about everything I can find. This is my first time using Jenkins.

**Background:**
I am using a Git repository and Jenkins.

**What I have:**
I have a batch file located in `hooks/` called `post-commit.bat`. The contents of the the batch file:

`#!bin/sh
echo "hook script started..."
curl http://XX.XX.X.XX:XXXX/job/JenkinsBuild/build?delay=0sec
echo "hook script ended..."
pause`

`JenkinsBuild` is the name of the job.

When I run this file from that location it works great and Jenkins does a build.

**The problem:**
I need this file to be executed when someone commits or pushes to the repository.
I don't understand how the scripts are executed. From what I've read I am under the impression that as long as it is a executable script it should just work.

**What I'm looking for:**
Is there something I am missing here? The other thought I had was that I need to change the the file path after the shebang.

[Edit]
Also, there are some default example files written that have .sample, I have tried removing the extension and also changing the extension to .bat, neither will run.

Comment: are you running this on windows?

Comment: Yes, I am running windows 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what was wrong, but I fixed it. I made a new bare bones git repo to see if I could get the Hooks to work locally. I deleted the .sample of one of the templates provided and it worked. So I copied that file and overwrote the file from local /hooks to the server /hooks. And it still worked. So I just edited that file to do what I had been doing in my batch file before. I have no explanation for why this fixed it but it now works.